# I Upload a laravel project into plesk and I have problems with laravel/sanctum

Tags: laravel, plesk, laravel-sanctum

I need some help...

I have uploaded to my plesk server a laravel project provided by a company.

However, it gives me the following error when displaying the web:
Whoops, something seems to have gone wrong.

When checking the Laravel.log I get the following message:

```
production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum' not found in /var/www/vhosts/sweet-tharp.51-254-103-53.plesk.page/httpdocs/config/sanctum.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/sweet-tharp.51-254-103-53.plesk.page/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(71): require()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/sweet-tharp.51-254-103-53.plesk.page/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Illuminate\Config\Repository))
#2 /var/www/vhosts/sweet-tharp.51-254-103-53.plesk.page/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(208): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/sweet-tharp.51-254-103-53.plesk.page/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(162): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/sweet-tharp.51-254-103-53.plesk.page/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(146): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->bootstrap()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/sweet-tharp.51-254-103-53.plesk.page/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/sweet-tharp.51-254-103-53.plesk.page/httpdocs/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 {main}
```

After investigating I have seen that you are not supposed to have laravel/sanctum installed.

However, when installing it I get the following error:

```
# composer require laravel/sanctum
Execution /usr/bin/php has failed with exit code 2, stdout: , stderr: Using version ^2.15 for laravel/sanctum
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/sanctum
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/sanctum ^2.15 -> satisfiable by laravel/sanctum[v2.15.0, v2.15.1].
    - laravel/sanctum[v2.15.0, ..., v2.15.1] require illuminate/console ^6.9|^7.0|^8.0|^9.0 -> found illuminate/console[v6.10.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.15] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/sanctum:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/sanctum:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I have checked and it is supposed to update the laravel/framework and let me install the sanctum, however I get the following error when doing so:

```
# composer update laravel/framework
Execution /usr/bin/php has failed with exit code 1, stdout: Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
    You can run './vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon' to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
    
In sanctum.php line 21:
                                             
  Class 'Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum' not found  
                                             

, stderr: Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package chumper/zipper is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-color is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-color instead.
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter instead.
Package laravelcollective/html is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use spatie/laravel-html instead.
Package maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package mtdowling/cron-expression is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use dragonmantank/cron-expression instead.
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler instead.
Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating optimized autoload files
Class Illuminate\Support\Traits\EnumeratesValues located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\Arr located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Arr.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\Enumerable located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Enumerable.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\HigherOrderCollectionProxy located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/HigherOrderCollectionProxy.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\MultipleItemsFoundException located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/MultipleItemsFoundException.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\LazyCollection located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/LazyCollection.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\ItemNotFoundException located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/ItemNotFoundException.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\Collection located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\Traits\Conditionable located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Conditionable/Traits/Conditionable.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\HigherOrderWhenProxy located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Conditionable/HigherOrderWhenProxy.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Mail\Feder located in ./app/Http/Mail/Feder.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Mail\Contacto located in ./app/Http/Mail/Contact.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Mail\Feder located in ./app/Http/Mail/Feder-antifraude.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
38 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

However, it doesn't, because it doesn't have laravel/sanctum installed.

Can anyone help me to solve the error?

The proofs and evidences are in the explanation.

Comment: HI! So I don't know Plesk, but I can't see anywhere that you aren't supposed to have Sanctum installed. What happens if you revert back to that fist error you encountered, and then run  composer update --lock?

Comment: Hi Mariann, same error: Class 'Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum' not found.

Comment: Its needed to know laravel version and also php version

Comment: Is it possible that it is because I have deployed a laravel 5.4 project on a laravel 9 installation?

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflict in your composer file. The version of sanctum you're trying to install isn't compatible with the console library. You should remove sanctum from the composer file and then run the following command to see which version is compatible with the other libraries you have installed:

```
composer require laravel/sanctum:*
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove laravel/sanctum but it doesn't work either, it says this:

```
# composer remove laravel/sanctum
Execution /usr/bin/php has failed with exit code 1, stdout: Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
    You can run './vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon' to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
    
In sanctum.php line 21:
                                             
  Class 'Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum' not found  
                                             

, stderr: laravel/sanctum is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/sanctum
Loading composer repositories with package information
Package "laravel/sanctum" listed for update is not locked.
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package chumper/zipper is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-color is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-color instead.
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter instead.
Package laravelcollective/html is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use spatie/laravel-html instead.
Package maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package mtdowling/cron-expression is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use dragonmantank/cron-expression instead.
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler instead.
Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating optimized autoload files
Class Illuminate\Support\Traits\EnumeratesValues located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\Arr located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Arr.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\Enumerable located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Enumerable.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\HigherOrderCollectionProxy located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/HigherOrderCollectionProxy.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\MultipleItemsFoundException located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/MultipleItemsFoundException.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\LazyCollection located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/LazyCollection.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\ItemNotFoundException located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/ItemNotFoundException.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\Collection located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\Traits\Conditionable located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Conditionable/Traits/Conditionable.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Support\HigherOrderWhenProxy located in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Conditionable/HigherOrderWhenProxy.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Mail\Feder located in ./app/Http/Mail/Feder.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Mail\Contacto located in ./app/Http/Mail/Contact.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Mail\Feder located in ./app/Http/Mail/Feder-antifraude.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
38 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

Anyway, for what it's worth I've also tried require laravel/sanctum:* but it gives me error too.

```
# composer require laravel/sanctum:*
Execution /usr/bin/php has failed with exit code 2, stdout: , stderr: Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/sanctum
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/sanctum[v0.1.0, ..., v0.2.1, v1.0.0] require illuminate/contracts ^6.0|^7.0 -> found illuminate/contracts[v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/sanctum[v1.0.1, v2.0.0, ..., v2.4.2] require illuminate/contracts ^6.9|^7.0 -> found illuminate/contracts[v6.10.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/sanctum[v2.5.0, ..., v2.13.0] require illuminate/contracts ^6.9|^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/contracts[v6.10.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/sanctum[v2.14.0, ..., v2.14.2] require illuminate/contracts ^6.9|^7.0|^8.0|^9.0 -> found illuminate/contracts[v6.10.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.15] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/sanctum[v2.15.0, ..., v2.15.1] require illuminate/console ^6.9|^7.0|^8.0|^9.0 -> found illuminate/console[v6.10.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.15] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/sanctum[v3.0.0, ..., v3.2.5] require php ^8.0.2 -> your php version (7.3.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/sanctum * -> satisfiable by laravel/sanctum[v0.1.0, v0.2.0, v0.2.1, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v2.0.0, ..., v2.15.1, v3.0.0, ..., v3.2.5].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```